# How do I import a csv file into an sqlite data with the use of PHP? What is the process?

Tags: php, sqlite, csv

I have a csv file and I would like to import this into an sqlite database with the use of php. I know this is a question similar to others but I would like to know what the process is so I also understand it.
After doing research on this issue I have only found snippets of code with no context on how this is achieved (Im not very techie as you can tell).

I want to import the csv file into the sqlite database and thats it. I have a table like so :

```
$db->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "weekData" (
    "week1" INTEGER,
    "week2" INTEGER,
    "week3" INTEGER,
    "week4" INTEGER
)');
```

And the csv file is called 'week.csv'

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What have you tried? It should not be too hard to read the CSV file, and then add one database row for each line in that file

Comment: I haven't yet. My original approach was to import a text file with 'LOAD DATA INFILE' before finding out sqlite doesn't support this. Now I am a bit lost haha @NicoHaase

Comment: So, what keeps you from writing code then?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451540/import-csv-file-into-a-sqlite-database-via-php or other tutorials about this topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import CSV File into a SQLite Database via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451540/import-csv-file-into-a-sqlite-database-via-php)

Answer (score 0):

I did not test the code, so use it only to get an idea about the steps.

```
<?php
// 1. Open the file
$filepath = 'test.csv';
$file = new SplFileObject($filepath);

// 2. Read each line of the CSV file until you get to the end of the file
while(($column = $file->fgetcsv()) !== false) {
   // for debuging you can print the values
   // $column[0] => first column
   // $column[1] -> second column
   print_r($column);


   // 3. insert the fields into DB
   // this depends a lot on what DB you use, so you have to figure it out yourself
   // make sure to escape the values you put in SQL to avoid SQL injection
   $db->query(...);
}

unset($file); // close the file
```